# Reactjs fetch headers not working properly

Tags: javascript, reactjs, cron, http-status-code-404, fetch-api

I'm trying to use fetch with react to get a response from an aws api gateway endpoint. I'm using custom authorizer with the endpoint. I can use curl with headers to successfully get data from the endpoint, as well as use the chrome extension postman to get the data successfully, but using the below code with react, I always get a 401 error even with a valid token. I'm somewhat new to react, but I think I have code that *should* work. What am I doing wrong? Is there something I need to change?

```
componentDidMount() {
Auth.currentAuthenticatedUser()
.then((res) => {
  let token = res.signInUserSession.idToken.jwtToken
  ///*
  let myHeaders = new Headers();
  myHeaders.append('authorization', token)
  myHeaders.append('type', 'TOKEN')
  fetch(<URL>, {headers: myHeaders})
  .then((res) => {
    console.log(res);
  })
  .catch((err) => {
    console.log(err);
  })
})
.catch((err) => {
  console.log(err);
})
```

}

Comment: Can you share the curl command?

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you need to enable CORS: http://docs.aws.amazon.com/apigateway/latest/developerguide/how-to-cors.html